# How do I get every file of an extension from a directory to another? I wrote a code but I'm getting an exception

Tags: python, rename, glob

This piece of code is my first attempt at creating a program. I'm getting an error when running it that reads:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process:
>   'C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\' -> 'C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\Planilhas
>   Excel\'

What am I doing wrong? The goal of this program is to get all excel, then pdf, then word files and put them in folders created by the program.

```
import os
from glob import glob

# import cx_Freeze
print("Digite o diretório de origem.")
dirOrigem = input()

os.chdir(dirOrigem)

excel_files = glob('*.xlsx')
excel_files.append(''.join(glob('*.xls')))

dirDestinoXL = dirOrigem + '\\' + 'Planilhas Excel'
if not os.path.exists(dirDestinoXL):
    os.makedirs(dirDestinoXL)

for i in excel_files:
    os.rename(f'{dirOrigem}\\{"".join(i)}', f'{dirDestinoXL}\\{"".join(i)}')

os.chdir(dirOrigem)

pdf_files = glob('*.pdf')

dirDestinoPDF = dirOrigem + '\\' + 'PDF'
if not os.path.exists(dirDestinoPDF):
    os.makedirs(dirDestinoPDF)

for p in pdf_files:
    os.rename(f'{dirOrigem}\\{"".join(p)}', f'{dirDestinoPDF}\\{"".join(p)}')


os.chdir(dirOrigem)

word_files = glob('*.doc')
word_files.append(glob('*.docx'))

dirDestinoWord = dirOrigem + '\\' + 'Word'
if not os.path.exists(dirDestinoWord):
    os.makedirs(dirDestinoWord)

for d in word_files:
    os.rename(f'{dirOrigem}\\{"".join(d)}', f'{dirDestinoWord}\\{"".join(d)}')
```

Comment: if any of those files are open in any other process, then close them and try again.

Comment: `excel_files = glob('*.xlsx')
excel_files.append(''.join(glob('*.xls')))
` Does the excel_files contain the correct excel files as expected? Maybe be empty list.

Comment: Remove this: excel_files.append(''.join(glob('*.xls'))) and it works fine. You are appending a blank section so your list looks like [''] which then your for loop tries to modify '' which it can't.

Comment: This is correct. I thought that and tried putting an If statement to check if it is empty but didn't manage to get it right. I'm going to read through glob's docs to see if I can look for any excel extensions otherwise I don't know how I should go about looking for both xlsx and xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your program and it doesn't work as it is on my computer. I changed some lines and it works. Hope it helps

```
import os
from glob import glob

dirOrigem = r'C:\Users\fchal\Desktop\temp' # here I changed the code just because I didn't want to bother using input()
os.chdir(dirOrigem)

excel_files = glob('*.xlsx')
excel_files.extend(glob('*.xls'))


dirDestinoXL = dirOrigem + '\\' + 'xlsfile'
if not os.path.exists(dirDestinoXL):
    os.makedirs(dirDestinoXL)

for i in excel_files:
    os.rename(i, os.path.join(dirDestinoXL, i))


# same procedure for pdf and word files
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I put the input because I'm not going to run that in my pc and I'll need the right directory on her pc. But I guess I'll just get her PC's directory.

Answer (score 1):

I know that `glob` can be a mess sometimes. And if the files are open, you can get errors. Here's what I would do:

```
import os

def move_files_with_extension(from_dir, to_dir, *extensions):
    if not os.path.isdir(from_dir):
        raise ValueError('{} is not a real directory'.format(from_dir))
    elif not os.path.isdir(to_dir):
        raise ValueError('{} is not a real directory'.format(to_dir))

    files_with_extensions = all_files_with_extensions_in(from_dir, *extensions)

    for file_path in files_with_extensions:
        os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(to_dir, os.path.basename(file_path)))

def all_files_with_extensions_in(dir, *extensions):
    files_with_extensions = list()

    for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(dir):
        for file_name in file_names:
            if file_name.endswith(extensions):
                files_with_extensions.append(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name))

    return files_with_extensions
```

and then you can do:

```
dirOrigem = input()

excel_location = os.path.join(dirOrigem, 'Planilhas Excel')

move_files_with_extension(dirOrigem, excel_location, '.xls', '.xlsx')
```

and so on

Comment: This is such a beauty. I still can't grasp how all this works. This is what is called good code and mine is what people call bad code? No problem in saying, this is my first program ever.

Comment: Lol! I would not call your code bad, nor my code good. Just different solutions to the same problem.